# Can someone explain CURL cookie handling (PHP)?

Tags: cookies, curl

honestly I'm having some trouble understanding the CURL options CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE and CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR.

If I set

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt')
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt')
```

Where is cookie.txt created? On the server? In which directory?

And the most stupid question:
does this handle all requests the curl-script is executing? So, if I have 200 requests, does CURL store all the request cookie information in a single file for alle 200 requests?

Maybe someone can give me  quick overview how this works, I didn't find a good tutorial on this and the documentation is quite poor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cookie.txt is on the same directory as your PHP script. cookie.txt is overwritten for every new curl handle.

Comment: So if 200 people are executing the script at the same time they overwrite other peoples cookie.txt?

Comment: N.B.: **You simply provide a full path to the file you want to use, it doesn't have to be in the same directory.**

Comment: And I found out you have to `session_start()` in your script. It seems obvious, but it was never mentionend anywhere.