# Handling multiple requests whilst using cURL's CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE option

Tags: php, cookies, curl

I'm using `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` to store cookies to a file and `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` to retrieve them from the file.

What I'm wonder is what happens when multiple users are accessing the script at the same time - won't it mess up the contents of the cookie file? Also, how do I manage the cookie files so that it's possible to have multiple users at the same time?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can someone explain CURL cookie handling (PHP)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105529/can-someone-explain-curl-cookie-handling-php)

Comment: If the answer in the duplicate is correct, it is even worse than a mess :)

Comment: @Pekka You can supply a full path to the file you want used. I'll drop a comment on that other question.

Comment: Incidentally, as the answers on this question are substantially better than the other question referenced above, I've tweaked the title/body text of this question for readability in the hope that this becomes the canonical resource for this topic.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to specify a different file for each execution of the script, otherwise you'll have issues with the file being overwritten, etc. as you suggest.

You might want to have a look at the [tempnam](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php) (example below) as a means of generating the unique file, or simply use [uniqid](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php), etc. and create the file yourself.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $cookieFilePath = $_SESSION['cookiefilepath']
                         ? $_SESSION['cookiefilepath']
                         : tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), session_id().'_cookie_');
    $_SESSION['cookiefilepath'] = $cookieFilePath;
    ...
    curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookieFilePath);
    ...
?>
```

That said, you'll need to ensure that you remove these files once they're no longer required. (If this isn't within the lifetime of your script, you might want to periodically execute a tidy-up script via cron that uses [filemtime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php) or similar.)

Incidentally, **you can simply provide a full path to the file you want to use** - it doesn't have to be in the same directory that the script is in, despite what is said in the existing [Can someone explain CURL cookie handling (PHP)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105529/can-someone-explain-curl-cookie-handling-php) question.

Comment: if you're gonna use `tempnam()` to create the file name, it will be different for each request. so you won't be able to reuse any cookies for subsequent requests doing that.

Comment: @Kris Good point - I'll tweak the example in a mo. Thanks for the heads-up. :-)

Answer (score 3):

`CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` and `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` are just utilities for handling cookies in a file, like a web browser.
And it's not recommended for your case.

But you can play directly with http headers to set and retrieve cookies.

For setting you cookies

```
<?php
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'user=xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx');
?>
```

For retrieving cookies, just identify the headers that startswith `Set-Cookie:`

You can check this document for understanding how cookie headers works http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html

Usage example, quick and dirty, but *definitely* **not standard**.

With this headers

```
<?php
$header_blob = '
Set-Cookie: PART_NUMBER=ROCKET_LAUNCHER_0001; path=/
Set-Cookie: PART_NUMBER=RIDING_ROCKET_0023; path=/ammo
';
```

Extract cookie headers

```
$cookies = array();
if (preg_match_all('/Set-Cookie:\s*(?P<cookies>.+?);/i', $header_blob, $matches)) {
    foreach ($matches['cookies'] as $cookie) {
        $cookies[] = $cookie;
    }
    $cookies = array_unique($cookies);
}
var_dump($cookies);
```

Resend cookies

```
$cookie_blob = implode('; ', $cookies);
var_dump($cookie_blob);
```

Comment: i want to use the cookie with the next set of curl commands.. and curl just allows retrieving from a file.. so if i identify too, how to pass it to the next curl statements ??

Answer (score 1):

Multiple requests will overwrite the same file (but will probably also slow all other requests execution down due to file locking).

You could incorporate the [`session_id()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php) into the cookie file name so you'll have one cookie file for every client session. I'd also recommend storing the files in something like [`sys_get_temp_dir()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sys-get-temp-dir.php).

something like:

```
$cookieFile = sys_get_temp_dir().PATH_SEPARATOR.session_id().'-cookies.txt';
```

Should work fine for that.